# meta predicates fixedpoint/3 and fixedpointlist/3

Tags: prolog

What about the following meta-predicate "fixed point"?

```
fixedpoint(P_2,X0,X) :-
   call(P_2,X0,X1),
   if_(X0 = X1, X = X0, fixedpoint(P_2,X1,X)).

fixedpointlist(P_2,X0,[X0|Xs]) :-
   call(P_2,X0,X1),
   if_(X0 = X1, Xs = [], fixedpointlist(P_2,X1,Xs)).
```

The implementation is based, in part, on [`if_/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915) and reified term equality [`(=)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29708684/4609915) by @false.

Are above definitions useful idioms?

Comment: Useful no doubt but your post could be improved with some usage examples.